# Dibujar datos de dos columnas diferentes en la misma gráfica. R

Tags: r

Tengo un archivo csv (`"datos.csv"`) con varias columnas. Mi variable dependiente es J y mi variables independientes son S1, S2, S3 y S4.

```
J  S1  S2  S3  S4  I
1  4   5   3   2   0
2  12  11  34  44  0
3  12  15  22  21  1
4  10  9   10  11  1
```

He conseguido hacer una gráfica con los datos de J y de S1:

```
reg.data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\datos.csv", header=TRUE, sep=';')
library(ggplot2)
qplot(data=reg.data, x=J, y= mean(S1), colour = "red")
```

Desearía que en la misma gráfica aparecieran los datos de todas mis variables independientes S1, S2, S3, S4, en diferentes colores. No consigo hacerlo.

También me gustaría saber cómo representar en una gráfica tres ejes: variable J, variables S (en el mismo eje) y covariable I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar cuando haces `mean(S1)` estas calculando el promedio de una sola columna por lo que la gráfica va a ser un único punto, si quieres graficar el promedio de S1 a S4, debe primero hacer un vector de la siguiente forma:

```
promedio <- as.data.frame(x = colMeans(reg.data[c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")]))
```

Es decir, calculamos el promedio de las cuatro columnas y lo convertimos en un `data.frame` para poder usarlo con ggplot. Ahora lo que hay que hacer es graficar estos nuevos datos de la siguiente forma:

```
paleta <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")
qplot(data=promedio, x=rownames(promedio), y=promedio[,1], colour = paleta)
```

Definimos primero una paleta de colores para cada punto, como X vamos a tener los `rownames(promedio)` es decir S1,S2,S3 y S4, como Y vamos a usar el valor calculado (promedio) de cada columna. Mas o menos así nos quedaría el gráfico:

[image: Primera versión]

Hay varias cosas que son mejorables, por lo que vamos a cambiar a `ggplot`, lo cual te recomiendo que hagas, de hecho en la propia documentación de `qplot` recomiendan saltar directamente a `ggplot`.

El ejemplo completo y verificable, sería así:

```
library(ggplot2)

list <-"J  S1  S2  S3  S4  I
        1  4   5   3   2   0
        2  12  11  34  44  0
        3  12  15  22  21  1
        4  10  9   10  11  1"

reg.data = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(list), header=TRUE))

promedio <- as.data.frame(x = colMeans(reg.data[c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")]))
paleta <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")
ggplot(promedio, 
        aes(x=rownames(promedio), y=promedio[,1])) +
        xlab("Valores") +
        ylab("Promedio") +        
        geom_point(size=5, colour=paleta)
```

El resultado:

[image: Segunda versión]

Como se puede observar ahora tenemos mayor control sobre las opciones del gráfico y hemos:

- Configurado tamaño y color de los puntos
- Configurado las etiquetas de X e Y